# Aristotle Metaphysics - questions on syntax

Tags: syntax, medieval-latin, ancient-greek, translation-explanation, aristotle

Metaphysics, 994b7-9:

> ἅμα δὲ καὶ ἀδύνατον τὸ πρῶτον ἀΐδιον ὂν φθαρῆναι: ἐπεὶ γὰρ οὐκ ἄπειρος ἡ γένεσις ἐπὶ τὸ ἄνω, ἀνάγκη ἐξ **οὗ φθαρέντος πρώτου** τι ἐγένετο μὴ ἀΐδιον εἶναι.

Latin translation:

> Simul autem impossibile primum sempiternum corrumpi. Quoniam enim non est infinita generatio in sursum, necesse ex **quo corrupto primo** aliquid factum est  non sempiternum esse.

Reeve's translation:

> For since coming to be is not without a limit in the upward direction, **the first thing from whose passing away** something came to be must be non-eternal.

I have two questions:

(1) I wonder why **πρώτου** and **primo** are not *accusative* as the subject of the indirect statement and they follow the *genitive* and *ablative* case of preceding words.

(2) I know that in Latin, **ex quo corrupto** is preferred over **ex cuius corruptione**. Now, I see that the case seems to be the same in Greek. I am looking for sources, both in Latin and Greek, that explain this preference (for example, the source which is not limited to explaining the preference of Gerundive over Gerund in Latin).

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Interesting question(s)! +1!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for your first question, you're right in pointing out that, given the context, one would expect something like "(...) *necesse primum [ex quo corrupto aliquid factum est] non sempiternum esse*", where the relative element *quo* would be a pronoun and its antecedent *primum* (singular neuter accusative, i.e. the subject of the infinitival clause) would be outside the relative clause. NB: as pointed out by TKR (see the comment below), Aristotle is talking about *primum*/τὸ πρῶτον in a technical sense.

Why don't we find this expected structure here? I don't know. Given that the context seems to exclude the quasi-adverbial reading of *primo* modifying *corrupto* (see the comments below), which would be associated to the (quite different!) interpretation "[that: elliptical antecedent *id*] from which being first corrupted something came" (e.g., cf. Reeve's translation in bold above), the only remaining possibility turns out to be the following one, which is based on the incorporated antecedent analysis. As pointed out by [A&G § 307b, p.186](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/relative-pronouns), it is typical of Latin (but not of English) that "the antecedent noun may [also] appear only in the relative clause, agreeing with the relative in case". Assuming this analysis, in the sentence at issue here, the "antecedent" *primo* is inside the relative clause and agrees with the relative *quo* in case (ablative). In this sentence *quo* is not a pronoun but rather an adjective modifying the substantivized category expressed by *primo* (again, recall that *primum/τὸ πρῶτον* is used in a technical sense here). This said, I do think that this particular sentence of Medieval Latin can be said to be a bit forced or unnatural (at least in Classical Latin).

As for your second question, to the extent that the so-called "dominant participle construction" (e.g. *ab urbe condita*) often sounds more natural/idiomatic than its corresponding verbal nominalization (cf. *ab urbis conditione*), you are right when claiming that *ex quo corrupto* can be preferred over *ex cuius corruptione*. Since you are looking for some references, my initial suggestion is that you could take a look at this recent work by Olga Spevak (2018):

Spevak, Olga (2018). "La construction à participe dominant vs. le nom verbal chez Cicéron". *Revue de Philologie* 92 (1): 63-84.

If you cannot read French, some brief remarks on the parallelism between eventive nouns and dominant participles are also included in Pinkster's (2021: 27-28) second volume of his monumental Oxford Latin Syntax. For instance, as pointed out by him, note that the following example from Tacitus can be paraphrased through an eventive noun: *occisio dictatoris*.

> Cum *occisus dictator* (...) pulcherrimum facinus videretur (Tac. *Ann.* 1.8.6)

Pinkster, Harm (2021). *The Oxford Latin Syntax. The Complex Sentence and Discourse*. Oxford: OUP.

If you're interested in "dominant participle constructions", you can also find some discussion in previous posts like the following ones: e.g., see [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/409/is-victa-serpente-an-ablative-absolute/8793#8793) and [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9412/how-obligatory-is-the-predicate-in-a-dominant-participle-construction), inter alia.

NB: The works above by Spevak and Pinkster are quite descriptive, whereby I think they are quite readable. In case you are also interested in more technical/fine-grained analyses of "dominant participle constructions", please let me know and I will provide you with some additional references.

Comment: Great. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I could find the parallel constructions in Greek.

Comment: @TKR The several translations I consulted are quite different from your interpretation ("from which being first corrupted something came"), which is based on the quasi-adverbial reading of _primo_ modifying _corrupto_. The translations I checked are _all_ coherent with the following reconstructed structure whereby _primum_ (i.e. τὸ πρῶτον) would be the antecedent and the true subject of the infinitival clause: _necesse (est) [primum [ex quo corrupto aliquid factum est] non sempiternum esse]_. That's why I advocated for an incorporated antecedent analysis (_primum>primo_).

Comment: This said, I do agree that this particular sentence in Medieval Latin can be said to sound forced or unnatural in Classical Latin.

Comment: After reading the context I tend to agree (so deleted my comment) -- Aristotle seems to be using τὸ πρῶτον in a technical sense.